# Retrieving variables from a text file through a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I am creating a school program for a project in which I a writing words and translations to a file, (separated by a character). I have read that I can read them via a hash map into an array. I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as how to do this.

If anyone has a better idea of how to store and retrieve the words I would love to learn. The reason I am writing to a file is so the user can store as many words as they want.

Thank-you so much :D

Comment: What do you mean by 'separated by a character'? You don't need a special character for this. You can separate them via a space.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder yeah... I just thought maybe they would use a space in the cards, so it would just be easier to use a very obscure character

Comment: Then you can use my method, but without the `FileString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` line, and you can do this: `FileString = FileString.split(SpecialCharacter)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.HashMap` to store user words and related translations:

```
String userWord = null;
        String translation = null, translation1 = null;

        Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap();
        map.put(userWord, new String[] { translation, translation1 });

        String[] translations = map.get(userWord);
```

This `map` lets you map single `userWord` to multiple translations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference for learning how to use BufferedReader: [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)
Here's a reference for learning how to use FileReader: [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

```
import java.io.*;
class YourClass
{
    public static void main() throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("FilePath"); // Replace every '\' with '/' in the file path
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "";
        String FileString = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Now 'line' contains each line of the file
            // If you want, you can store the entire file in a String, like this:
            FileString += line + "\n"; // '\n' to register each new line
        }

        System.out.println(FileString);
    }
} // End of class
```

I'm still a newbie, and don't understand much about `HashMap`, but I can tell you how to store it in a String array:

```
FileString = FileString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
String[] Words = FileString.split(" ");
```

`FileString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` - Replaces 1 or more spaces with 1 space, so as to avoid any logical errors.

`FileString.split(" ")` - Returns a String array of each String separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    File f = new File("/Desktop/Codes/Text.txt");
    // enter your file location
    HashMap<String, String[]> hs = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    // throw exception in main method
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    String s="";
    while(sc.hasNext()){
       s = sc.next();
       // create a method to search translation
       String []trans = searchTrans(s);
       hs.put(s, trans);

    }
```